# Changing variable in different module

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a minesweeper game, and I'm looking to set the number of flags a user has based on the number of rows in the gameboard. I have these two things in different modules, and I'm not sure why I can't get the modules to communicate correctly. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I can't quite figure out what.

```
var gameboard = (function() {

var initialize = function(rows, cols) {
    var flags = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            flags++;
            for(var y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
                var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
                unit.width(($('#gameboard').width() / cols) - 2).height(($('#gameboard').height() / rows) - 2).appendTo('#gameboard');
            }
        }

    addId(rows, cols);
    gatherMines(rows);
    setFlags(flags);
};

var setFlags = function(number) {
    gamePlay.flagCount = number;
}

return {
    initialize: initialize,
    flags: setFlags
};

}());
```

---

```
var gamePlay = (function() {

var flagCount;

return {
    go: go,
    flagCount: flagCount
};

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `gamePlay` an object:

```
var Gameplay = function(flagCount) {
    this.flagCount = flagCount;
};
```

You can now just create an instance of the `GamePlay` object in your Gameboard object. For example inside your `initialize` method:

```
var gp = {};

var initialize = function(){
    gp = new Gameplay(0);
}
```

You can now use `gp` anywhere, as long as `initialize()` has been executed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there anyway to directly set the flag count from my gameboard module though? I have other function in my gamePlay module that I omitted for brevity, and for whatever reason, this solution has me confused